# How can I debug the Main() method in ASP.NET Core running on Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure-web-app-service

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-azure-app-service?view=vs-2022) shows how to attach the Visual Studio Debugger to a running process on my Azure app service. But it does not show how to restart the app and keep the debugger connected. I need to debug some code in my `Main()` method.

How can I do that?

This is a Blazor server-side app.

Program.cs in my Blazor app:

```
internal class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        var version = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetAssemblyFileVersion();
        Debug.WriteLine($"Application starting up - version: {version}");
```

I want to set a breakpoint on the `var version =` line of code and have the debugger break there when the app is started.

Comment: Can you please be more clear about your ask.What you are excatly looking for?

Comment: @Harshitha I added more details. TIA

Comment: Are you able to hit the breakpoint first time?

Comment: @Harshitha No. Because when I tell Azure to restart the app, it then disconnects from the debugger.

Comment: AFAIK,that is the default behaviour of the app to get disconnected from the process.We need to manually attach the process again after restart.

Comment: Even I am unable to hit the breakpoint in `Program.cs` file.Trying from my end.Will let you know once done

Comment: @Harshitha Right. But when I reattach, `Main()` has already executed. There's no way to debug that startup code that I've found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256183/discussion-between-harshitha-and-david-thielen).

Comment: Did you find any alternative option for this?

Comment: @Harshitha Nope.

Answer (score 0):

> it does not show how to restart the app and keep the debugger connected.

Once we restart the Application, the process which you have attached to debug will be lost.

Even this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-azure?view=vs-2022) says the same.

After restart, if you want to continue with the same process, we can use `Reattach to process`.

[image]

This option lets us to continue with the same process which we are debugging before restart.

- But the main method cannot be debugged.
  Startup code gets executed only once. That is every time after the restart.

As I already mentioned in the comments that is the default behavior of the app to get disconnected from the process. We need to manually attach the process again after restart.

The Remote debugging which is explained in the MS Doc which you are following is a bit lengthy and manual process.

Another easy option to Remote debug is to use `Attach Debugger` in `Publish` => `Hosting` profile section.

[image]

This doesn't require any connection/process to be attached by us.

All the settings will be done on its own. It finds the process on its own.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that does not solve my question - debugging Main(). By the time you attach with the debugger, Main() has completed and your app is not started. (Or in the case of the bug I was trying to fix, the bug has been hit, the exception thrown, and the app has exited.)